# Aspectj pointcut to capture a stream closing (trying to measure bytes sent / received via sockets)

Tags: java, sockets, aspectj

I'm trying to make a basic aspect (as a proof-of-concept, mainly) that I can use to keep track of IO done over sockets.

The following code wraps any calls to get the input stream from a socket with a Commons-IO based CountingInputStream. That part works.

What's not working (and I suspect it is because I fubar'ed my pointcut definition) is getting the number of bytes out of the CountingInputStream.

The close / reset advice is never being hit. (I had it as an @Before advice prior to switching it to @Around - but that wasn't working either...)

(Once I get the basic thing working I do plan to clean it up a bit more too)

```
package com.foo.io;

import com.yammer.metrics.Metrics;
import com.yammer.metrics.core.Counter;
import com.yammer.metrics.core.Histogram;
import com.yammer.metrics.core.MetricName;
import com.yammer.metrics.core.MetricsRegistry;
import org.apache.commons.io.input.CountingInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.CountingOutputStream;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;


@Aspect
public class SocketStreamWrapper {
    // can trivially create a map keeping track of bytes sent to / from a given address if this is desired
    final Counter inboundByteCounter;
    final Histogram inboundByteHistogram;
    final Counter outboundByteCounter;
    final Histogram outboundByteHistogram;

    public SocketStreamWrapper() {
        inboundByteCounter = Metrics.defaultRegistry().newCounter(new MetricName("inbound", "bytes", "counted"));
        inboundByteHistogram = Metrics.defaultRegistry().newHistogram(new MetricName("inbound", "bytes", "histogram"), true);
        outboundByteCounter = Metrics.defaultRegistry().newCounter(new MetricName("outbound", "bytes", "counted"));
        outboundByteHistogram = Metrics.defaultRegistry().newHistogram(new MetricName("outbound", "bytes", "histogram"), true);
    }

    @Pointcut("call(* java.net.Socket.getInputStream()) && target(s)")
    void input(Socket s) {
    }

    @Pointcut("call(* CountingInputStream.close()) && this(cis)")
    void close(CountingInputStream cis) {
    }

    @Pointcut("call(* CountingInputStream.reset()) && this(cis)")
    void reset(CountingInputStream cis) {
    }

    @Pointcut("call(* CountingInputStream+.read*()) && this(cis)")
    void read(CountingInputStream cis) {

    }

    @Around("close(cis)")
    public void closeCountingStream(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, CountingInputStream cis) throws Throwable {
        inboundByteCounter.inc(cis.getByteCount());
        inboundByteHistogram.update(cis.getByteCount());
        cis.resetByteCount();
        jp.proceed();
    }

    @Around("input(s)")
    public Object wrapInputStream(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
                                  Socket s)
            throws Throwable {
        InputStream in = (InputStream) joinPoint.proceed();
        return new CountingInputStream(in);
    }

    @Pointcut("call(* java.net.Socket.getOutputStream()) && target(s)")
    void output(Socket s) {
    }

    @Around("output(s)")
    public Object wrapOutputStream(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
                                   Socket s)
            throws Throwable {
        OutputStream out = (OutputStream) joinPoint.proceed();
        return new CountingOutputStream(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work:

`    @Pointcut("call(* java.net.Socket.getInputStream()) && target(s)")
    void input(Socket s) {
    }
    
    @Pointcut("call(* java.io.Closeable+.close(..)) && target(cis)")
    void closeInputStream(CountingInputStream cis) {
    }
    
    @Pointcut("call(* java.io.Closeable+.close(..)) && target(cis)")
    void closeOutputStream(CountingOutputStream cis) {
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you need to use *target* instead of *this* is that the *target* condition indicates that the pointcut applies to the object that the method is being called upon, not the caller of the method. In this case the object that your *close*, *reset* and *read* pointcuts are targeting is the CountingInputStream.

The distinction between the two is outlined in: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html

As an additional point, you may want to have a subclass of CountingInputStream with a private or protected scope so that you can target it directly and avoid accidentally interacting with others using  CountingInputStreams. Your implementation of *closeCountingStream* calls *resetByteCount()* which would cause confusion and delay for other use cases.